# Any MSVC equivalent to GCC '-include' flag?

Tags: gcc, cross-platform, include, visual-c++

In GCC you can use the '-include ' flag to automatically include a file in the compilation unit. Is there any equivalent method for this in MSVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS, you'll find it as: "Forced Include Files".
The tag is `/FI`

Comment: I've just edited this so it is clear that the second letter of the command line option is capital-eye and not lower-case-ell.